# PHP variable in path name for file_exists() not working

Tags: php

I am using

```
if (file_exists($file_pointerTOB))
```

in a table to show a tick or a cross if the file exists.

```
$file_pointerTOB = '../uploads/clientupload/TOB-AR001.pdf';
```

Works and shows either a tick or cross where the file is TOB-AR001.pdf

However

```
$file_pointerTOB = '../uploads/clientupload/TOB-'.$row['ref'].'.pdf';
```

Does not work and shows a cross even though the file exists.
I have tried variants of `'.$row['ref'].'` but i don't understand why this isn't working.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*The whole of the code is below. *

```
    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

                  $file_pointerTOB = '../uploads/clientupload/TOB-'.$row['ref'].'.pdf'; 
                   
                  echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<th>Client ID</th>";
                    echo "<th>Client Name</th>";
                                    echo "<th>Terms of Business</th>";  
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                    echo "</thead>";
                                    echo "<tbody>";

                  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    echo "<td>" .  $row['ref'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] .   "</td>";
                                    echo"<td>";
                                            
                  if (file_exists($file_pointerTOB))  
                  { 
                  echo '<img src="ticksm.jpg"/>';
                  } 
                  else 
                  { 
                  echo '<img src="crosssm.jpg"/>';
                  } 
                                            
                  echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Can you echo out the `$file_pointerTOB` you get?

Comment: Because `$row['ref'] != 'AR001'`, perhaps it is empty or contains unexpected characters.

Comment: `$row` doesn't exist up there, move that `$file_pointerTOB = ...` line to _inside_ your `while`. [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display?rq=1)

Comment: @brombeer You sir are a star, how did i not see that ! Thank you so very very much it all works now.

Answer (score 1):

With thanks to @brombeer.
The variable was outside the *while* loop.

Working code below:

```
if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

            
               
              echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                            echo "<thead>";
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<th>Client ID</th>";
                echo "<th>Client Name</th>";
                                echo "<th>Terms of Business</th>";  
                                echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";

              while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

              $file_pointerTOB = '../uploads/clientupload/TOB-'.$row['ref'].'.pdf'; 

                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" .  $row['ref'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $row['name'] .   "</td>";
                                echo"<td>";
                                        
              if (file_exists($file_pointerTOB))  
              { 
              echo '<img src="ticksm.jpg"/>';
              } 
              else 
              { 
              echo '<img src="crosssm.jpg"/>';
              } 
                                        
              echo "</td>";
```